# Does the LPC1343 MCU need an external clock for USB operation?

Tags: microcontroller, usb, arm, crystal, nxp

I am trying to design a board using the LPC1343: http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/LPC1311_13_42_43.pdf

I would like to be able to use its on-board USB bootloader to program it. My question is whether or not my board requires an external 12 MHz oscillator. I am confused because in the user manual (http://www.nxp.com/documents/user_manual/UM10462.pdf) it seems that there is an internal 12 MHz:

"12 MHz Internal high-frequency RC oscillator (IRC) that can optionally be used as 
a system clock" (page 7)

Does my design need an external clock to work with the USB programming? Ideally I'd like to use it as a USB mass storage device to drag-and-drop .bin files to program it. Thanks.

Comment: Full speed should be able to use internal RC oscillator. You can not use IRC with high speed USB

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, the IRC oscillator is not precise enough to use for USB. This is why the LPC13xx series has a separate PLL for USB. Quoting document [AN11392](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCsQFjAA&url=http://www.nxp.com/documents/application_note/AN11392.pdf&ei=s1dPU560EM6GyATJ_4CoDA&usg=AFQjCNEAM-CsPiVyyQs3KTvnLOHhr3lM0A&sig2=5jJ41_XJAiXcoTC894EQGQ&bvm=bv.64764171,d.aWw): Guidelines for full-speed USB on NXP's LPC microcontrollers:

*When using a full-speed USB peripheral, it is important to use an external crystal, or a 
tight frequency tolerance ceramic resonator, for the timing element. The internal 12 MHz 
±1 % RC oscillator, while very accurate, does not have the accuracy required for USB. 
The USB peripheral operates at a clock frequency of 48 MHz, so the crystal must be 
chosen such that a multiple of its frequency is equal to 48 MHz. A parallel resonant 
12 MHz crystal with a data signaling tolerance of 0.25 %, or ±2500 ppm is required.*

Comment: Thank you for explaining this, I've changed my design as a result. Cheers.